# Using CSS :not selector in LESS nested rules

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

```
.outerclass {
    h3 {
        color: blue;
    }
    p:not(.nested) {
        color: green;
    }
}
```

In the LESS example above I wish to target all "p" elements within a div class "outerclass" but NOT the p elements within the further nested div called ".nested" - it does not work but instead makes all p elements green. I have tried...

```
p:not(.nested p) // excludes all p elements
```

and also...

```
p:not(.nested > p) // excludes all p elements
```

...to no avail. Is this possible or what am I missing? I am brand new to LESS

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is not a LESS issue as much as your css selector syntax. The `p:not(.nested)` is saying all `p` elements without the `.nested` class *themselves*, what you state is that the `.nested` class is on a `div` in which the `p` resides, so you need this:

```
.outerclass {
    h3 {
        color: blue;
    }
    :not(.nested) p,
    > p {
        color: green;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I removed the `div` and added the direct child `p` instance, so that the CSS output would properly target all `p` in `.outerclass` except for the exception.

**CSS Output for `p` elements would be**

```
.outerclass :not(.nested) p,
.outerclass > p {
  color: green;
}
```

The above will target any direct child `p` elements and any nested `p` elements in `.outerclass` except those that are children of your `.nested` element.

**An issue**

The issue BoltClock is noting is if the `p` is nested deeper than being the immediate child of the `.nested` element. [See this fiddle where the last `p` element is still targeted even though it is within a `.nested` class](http://jsfiddle.net/Lubpt/).

If the `p` element will always be the direct child of `.nested` there is no issue. Or if the `.nested` is always the direct child of `.outerclass` but the `p` maybe nested deeper, then the above selector can be changed to `> :not(.nested) p` to produce CSS of `.outerclass > :not(.nested) p` which [will then work for all `p` under `.nested`](http://jsfiddle.net/Lubpt/1/).

The problem will be if the `.nested` in relation to `.outerclass` and the `p` within `.nested` are *both at some arbitrary depth to those parents*. No css selector could handle that adequately.

Comment: Note that `:not(.nested) p` is not equivalent to the hypothetical `:not(.nested p)`. Instead, it means any `p` that has an ancestor that is `:not(.nested)`. Granted your selector qualifies it with a `div`, but it's still a very fragile selector.

Comment: @BoltClock: Since this is LESS code, the final output selector in my example would be `.outerclass div:not(.nested) p`, which appears to match what the OP is seeking based off the explanation given to "target all 'p' elements within a div class 'outerclass' but NOT the p elements within the further nested div called '.nested'".

Comment: Thanks for your answer ScottS but it is still not working for me - all p elements are not selected. I think BoltClock's answer throws some light on it for me though - I am gleaning from this that it is not really possible using this format.

Comment: @ScottS: That depends very much on the HTML structure. If there won't be any other `div` elements separating `.outerclass` and the `p` elements, then such a selector may work (although it'd be better to use child selectors instead of descendant selectors then). Otherwise, using descendant selectors with `:not()` will often have unwanted side effects.

Comment: @user2317093: I've updated as my answer would not originally have targeted all `p`, but should be now.

Comment: @BoltClock: indeed, I've added some clarification and fiddle examples to my answer to discuss the constraints the html must meet to make a css selection possible.

Comment: Great thanks, being new to LESS I am still getting my head around it

Comment: @user2317093: You are welcome. However, like I noted in my answer, your issue really had nothing to do with LESS itself, but rather what the CSS selector itself was that you needed (which could have been written in CSS without the help of LESS).